# Python Eve Session Management

Tags: session, eve

I'm writing an web application where I'm using python-eve + mongodb for rest api and angular2 for front end.
Now I'm not sure how to manage user session in python-eve after authentication.
Do I need to write custom middle-ware like Django provide by default?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Shashank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are using a REST API and one of the core principles of REST is, precisely, the lack of state/session. Each request carries an authorisation token (or equivalent info depending on the type of authentication) since the server does not maintain state between sessions.

With this being said I know that people have been doing exactly what you are asking for, but really, I would not do that in a REST context.

Comment: Thanks Nicola for the clarification!